# Reviewing/Approving Post Edits for http -> https

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I'm seeing a lot of 'http -> https' suggested edits show-up in the review queue to be reviewed and approved ([example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/207693)).  Almost all of these are several years-old posts that don't have any other changes except for edits to a link.

I went thru 5 of these types of edits just this morning.

I understand the [netword-wide move to https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) and I don't have any problem with that.  **I'm just wondering if it's a good use or our time to be reviewing/approving dozens of these types of edits each day?**  I know I could just hit <kbd>Skip</kbd> during the review but then I'm just pushing that decision to a different reviewer and that's not fair to them.

I read the meta post about the move to https as well as all, well...most, of the answers & comments there to try to find guidance on this topic. I believe things like this were to be handled on a site-by-site basis so I'm bringing it up here to ask for guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest refraining from any sort of manual cleanup on this. The system cleanup is scripted and unless you are in making a substantive edit and happen to fix http / https you are causing human review effort for something that can / should be automated.

If you find breakage systematically - please raise a bug question here on meta - new questions here summon all moderators with a notification.

Comment: FWIW, a Stack Overflow employee approved my HTTPS edits on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/51411). I'd take that as a clear sign that this process will not be automated. Flooding the edit queue is a valid concern of which I'm aware (see the linked post in grgarside's answer), so that's another reason to vote for me as moderator :)

Answer (score 2):

[@Glorfindel is going around the tag wikis and moving links to HTTPS.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26540/78482)

In my opinion, this is mostly fine:

- the links are tidied in other ways too if necessary
- the edits are on tag wikis so no bumping occurs
- Ask Different generally has a low number of items in the review queue so it's not preventing other edits from going through (we're nowhere near the queue cap)

One could argue this is farming reputation, but I would still say the benefits outweigh this.